# Samsung Smart TV -Get Device ID in Emulator

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

Im totaly new to the Samsung Smart TV App Development.Im trying to get Device Serial (MAC Address or any unique String) when the app is running.Here is what i have done so far.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test2</title>

    <!-- TODO : Common API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>


    <!-- TODO : Javascript code -->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/Main.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO : Style sheets code -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/stylesheets/Main.css" type="text/css">

    <!-- TODO: Plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
       var networkPlugin = document.getElementById('pluginNetwork');
       var nnaviPlugin = document.getElementById('pluginObjectNNavi');
       var deviceId = nnaviPlugin.GetDUID(networkPlugin.GetHWaddr());

       document.getElementById('ss').innerHTML = nnaviPlugin;
    }
    </script>

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="lycaload();" bgcolor="#FFF" style="background:#FFF">

fgujhdfughufdghudfhgufghufhgfc
<object id='pluginNetwork' border=0 classid='clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-  NETWORK'></object>
<object id='pluginObjectNNavi' border=0 classid='clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-NNAVI'>  </object>
    <!-- Dummy anchor as focus for key events -->
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="anchor" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();">   </a>

    <div id="ss">
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

This application is testing on 2014 Samsung Smart TV Emulator 5.1 and receiving nothing when app is running.  Please don't mark this as duplicate. I have followed previous Stackoverflow post and didnt get any luck..

Comment: is you code works fine for you in 2013 and 2012 emulators?

Comment: I didnt check on them..i saw in samsung forum that emulators does not have DUID.Is that correct?

Comment: So is there any unique identifier to recognize each TV separately,which is also working fine with emulators?

Comment: GetDUID method works on emulator, at least on 2011 and 2012, i did not checked others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from network plugin you get MAC address like this:

```
var mac = networkPlugin.GetMAC(0) || networkPlugin.GetMAC(1); // wired or wireless MAC address

if (!mac) {
    mac = 0;
}

console.log(String(mac).toUpperCase());
```

But I should recommend that better solution is using unique identifier from player (there is unique ID for playing DRM content)

```
<object id='EXTERNALWIDGET' border=0 classid='clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-EXTERNALWIDGETINTERFACE'>  </object>
try {
var externalPlugin= document.getElementById('EXTERNALWIDGET');

console.log(externalPlugin.GetESN("WIDEVINE"));
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do i need to add anything to head section for this ? because IDE is not showing proposals..

Comment: Iam getting "0" for externalPlugin.GetESN("WIDEVINE") on Emulator. Is this working on Real Device without problem?

Comment: It works only on real devices starting with 2011 models, all emulators will return invalid values.

Comment: Yes in the real device it works without problem. It cannot work in the emulator, because DRM is supported only on the real devices. I expect, that you want develop app in real device not in emulator... :-)